# Count variables and constraints PuLP and CP-Sat

Tags: optimization, or-tools, pulp, cp-sat

Does anyone know how I can get a print of the number of variables and constraints created in each optimization problem created in Python both CP-Sat and PuLP?

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

I'm not familiar with CP-sat, but in PuLP the `LpProblem` class has a method `numVariables()` which will return the number of variables.

For example:

```
import pulp

prob = pulp.LpProblem("minimize",pulp.LpMinimize)

single_var = pulp.LpVariable('single_var')
set_of_var = pulp.LpVariable.dicts("x_i,j", ((i, j) for i in range(3) for j in range(2)))

print(prob.numVariables())

# Add objective
prob += single_var + pulp.lpSum([set_of_var[i, j] for i in range(3) for j in range(2)])
print(prob.numVariables())

# Solve
prob.solve()
print(prob.numVariables())
```

Will return:

```
0
0
7
```

Note that variables are only counted once they've been added to the model (in the objective or constraints), and the model has been solved.

Comment: It seems that numVariables() works before solving now

Answer (score 0):

With CP-SAT:

```
  num_int_or_bool_vars = len(model.Proto().variables)
```

I have changed the API in the future 10.0. It will be PEP8 compliant.
The API will be:

```
  num_int_or_bool_vars = len(model.proto.variables)
```

Answer (score -1):

you can do this:

```
count=0
for v in prob.variables():
    count+=1
```